# Apple Server.app setup hangs on `Preparing Mail service...`

Tags: macos, osx-server, server.app

Each time I attempt to install Apple's Server.app, I get a hang at the point wherein it says, `Preparing Mail service...`.

I am trying to set this up via both the GUI and the shell (`sudo /Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/sbin/server setup`) with the same result.

I've performed `rm /Library/Server` and gone a bit further with removing some other folders:

```
sudo mv /.ServerBackups /var/db/.ServerSetupDone /Library/Preferences/com.apple.serverd.plist /Library/Preferences/com.apple.servermgr_accounts.plist /Library/Preferences/com.apple.servermgr_certs.plist /Library/Preferences/com.apple.servermgr_info.plist /Library/Preferences/com.apple.servermgrd.plist /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.apple.serverd /Library/Server ~/tmp/server_backup
```

Any idea of any other steps I can take to troubleshoot this here?

I've been thinking that perhaps I can use `sudo iosnoop` or such to scrub through what files may be active during this setup, but I've not really been able to isolate any problems so far...

Comment: Is this a new Mac setup or was server installed on an older OS? Typically mail isn't configured when you run setup - but perhaps there's some history? (I'll see if I have any ideas - but `fs_usage` and `tail`ing the system.log and install.log might be where I'd start looking as I don't use `iosnoop` much.

Comment: Also - can you run `/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/sbin/serverdiagnose` run when things are stuck?

Comment: Another good place to look for info on what is happening during setup/promotion is `/Library/Logs/ServerSetup.log`